# Bash one liner: How to nest curly braces for list generation inside a curly brace command group?

Tags: bash

The goal is to create a one line (copy and paste) bash command. The bash one line command should partition and format a drive, and when that results in a mountable volume, some initial maintenance commands.

The goal is to execute a list of commands when `cd /Volumes/VolumeName` succeeds in the current shell context. This grouping of commands can be done in bash by using curly braces. When `cd /Volumes/VolumeName` fails (`echo $?` != 0) further command execution is not necessary and command execution can stop.

The result of command `cd /Volumes/$VOL && {sudo rm -fr .{,_.}{fseventsd,Spotlight-V100,Trashes}; mkdir .fseventsd;}` is:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

The bottleneck might be that one of the commands in the curly braced command list is using curly braces for list generation: `sudo rm -fr .{,_.}{fseventsd,Spotlight-V100,Trashes}`.

How to nest curly braces for list generation inside a curly brace command group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing a necessary leading space. Consider:

```
mini:~ michael$ { echo sudo rm -fr .{,_.}{fseventsd,Spotlight-V100,Trashes}; echo mkdir .fseventsd;}
sudo rm -fr .fseventsd .Spotlight-V100 .Trashes ._.fseventsd ._.Spotlight-V100 ._.Trashes
mkdir .fseventsd
mini:~ michael$ {echo sudo rm -fr .{,_.}{fseventsd,Spotlight-V100,Trashes}; echo mkdir .fseventsd;}
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

If you look in `man 1 bash` under the *Compound Commands* section you'll see this (emphasis mine):

> { list; }
>
> list is simply executed in the current shell environment.  list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon. This  is known  as a group command.  The return status is the exit status of list.  Note that unlike the metacharacters ( and ), **{ and } are reserved words** and must occur where a reserved word is permitted to be recognized.  **Since they do not cause a word break, they must be separated from list by whitespace**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with the nested braces. Try with this:

```
cd /Volumes/$VOL && (sudo rm -fr .{,_.}{fseventsd,Spotlight-V100,Trashes}; mkdir .fseventsd;)
```

If you want to use a subshell, the rigth way is to use "()" instead of "{}".
Using "()" you don't need to add an extra space at the beginning of the command.

Comment: But he doesn't want to use a subshell. That's clear because he says *…in the current shell context*.

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces around braces that are used to command grouping. `{ sudo ...` insead of `{sudo ...`